# Имеет ли смысл подготавливать все запросы к БД во время ее инициализации или лучше делать это прямо перед выполнением запроса?

Tags: golang

Сейчас я инициализирую базу примерно таким образом:

```go
func NewDB(ctx context.Context, conf *envvar.VaultConfiguration) *pgx.Conn {
    get := func(v string) string {
        res, err := conf.Get(v)
        if err != nil {
            logrus.Fatalf("Не удалось получить значение конфигурации для %s: %v", v, err)
        }

        return res
    }

    dbUsername := get("PGDB_USERNAME")
    dbUserPassword := get("PGDB_PASSWORD")
    dbHost := get("PGDB_HOST")
    dbPort := get("PGDB_PORT")
    dbName := get("PGDB_NAME")

    dbURL := fmt.Sprintf(
        "postgres://%s:%s@%s:%s/%s",
        dbUsername, dbUserPassword, dbHost, dbPort, dbName,
    )

    db, err := pgx.Connect(ctx, dbURL)
    if err != nil {
        logrus.Fatalf("Не удалось подключиться к базе данных: %v", err)
    }

    if err := db.Ping(ctx); err != nil {
        logrus.Fatalf("Не удалось пингануть БД: %v", err)
    }

    if err := initPostRequests(ctx, db); err != nil {
        logrus.Fatal(err)
    }

    return db
}

func initPostRequests(ctx context.Context, db PGDB) error {
    if _, err := db.Prepare(
        ctx, "Insert.Post.",
        `INSERT INTO posts (text, author_id, created_at) VALUES ($1, $2, current_timestamp) RETURNING id`,
    ); err != nil {
        return fmt.Errorf("ошибка подготовки запроса Insert.Post.: %w", err)
    }

    if _, err := db.Prepare(ctx, "Update.Post.Id", `UPDATE posts SET text = $2 WHERE id = $1`); err != nil {
        return fmt.Errorf("ошибка подготовки запроса Update.Post.Id: %w", err)
    }

    return nil
}
```

и мне интересно не будет ли лучше подготавливать запрос непосредственно перед его выполнением в функции, то есть примерно таким образом:

```go
type PGDB interface {
    Exec(context.Context, string, ...interface{}) (pgconn.CommandTag, error)
    Prepare(context.Context, string, string) (*pgconn.StatementDescription, error)
}

type Queries struct {
    db PGDB
}

func (q *Queries) CreatePost(ctx context.Context, authorId int, text string) error {
    if _, err := q.db.Prepare(
        ctx, "Insert.Post.",
        `INSERT INTO posts (text, author_id, created_at) VALUES ($1, $2, current_timestamp) RETURNING id`,
    ); err != nil {
        return fmt.Errorf("ошибка подготовки запроса Insert.Post.: %w", err)
    }

    if _, err := q.db.Exec(ctx, "Insert.Post.", text, authorId); err != nil {
        return err
    }

    return nil
}
```

Comment: Лучше вынести initPostRequests в отдельный файл для засеивания и миграций (migration/seeding), который будет выполняться по необходимости.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ответ больше похож на код-ревью. Это будет моим сугубо личным мнением.

1. в `NewDB` лучше передавать `connectionURL string`, максимум специально созданный `DBConfig`, который содержит поля `dbUsername, dbUserPassword, dbHost, dbPort, dbName`. Это намного гибче и легче будет
2. я не любитель заранее подготовленных statements, как в`initPostRequests`. Это хорошо, когда у тебя до 5 запросов. А что делать, если их 50? Какие названия для них придумать? А когда они лежат внутри функции, как в `CreatePost`, то более наглядно будет, что и как конкретно будет исполнен запрос.
   можно INSERT INTO вынести в константы и использовать их оттуда, как вариант